# caching forms for different requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a MVC4 application with Razor.

users will be able to edit entities on this page, but since MVC-style urls look like this:

```
~/{Entity}/Edit/{Id}  
~/MyEntity/Edit/1
~/MyEntity/Edit/2
```

I fear that the client will not load the form from the cache.

i am currently always responding the empty form and filling data later with an ajax request. I'd love to keep the url style and somehow tell the client that he already got the form (from a request with different Id)

Answer (score 0):

You can add another parameter to your controller actions

for example right now you have

```
~/MyEntity/Edit/1
```

so i am assuming it looks something like

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

you can simply add another parameter:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, int loadFromCache)
{
 if(loadFromCache == 1)
 {
    //do something
 }
 else
 {
    //proceed regularly
 }
}
```

this way you can pass another parameter by which you will be able to do  an if statement

```
~/MyEntity/Edit/1?loadFromCache=1
```

Comment: my concern is the client-side caching... i want the browser to load the form for /Edit/2 from cache because its the same form as /Edit/1 and i will populate the form fields from an ajax request :)